# Volume control problems on laptop

Tags: sound, volume-control, amixer

Installed Ubuntu on Huawei matebook s14, everything seems fine except volume control.
When pressing volume up/down buttons in alsamixer 'Speaker' mixer goes up/down, but it doesn't do anything. 'Headphones' mixer is the one controlling volume, how to make buttons control the right mixer?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 23.04
I'm new to all this linux stuff, just trying something new for working laptop, thought the last one would be better

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem with a daemon. Try it: https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and add some more instruction for how to install and start the daemon? As it currently is, your answer is not much more than the link in it, so not very useful to most users. Thanks!